# How do I split a file with 4,000 lines into 20 parts (files) Notepad++?

Tags: html

I have a big HTML file with about **4,000 lines** of code.

When I run it, my browser crashes.

How can I split the file in 20 parts (*files*)?

Here is an image, it's all the way down like this:

[image]

Comment: This depends on HTML file - let's take a look at it.

Comment: What you actually want to achieve? Browser can actually crash too when opening 20 of them at once. I think you should make it read it  at least half sync, not async (your browser probably loads it asynchronously now and get stuck somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [Splity - Split long HTML files](http://sourceforge.net/projects/splity/)...

> ### Description
>
> A Perl script that splits a long HTML file into separate
> inter-linked pages, according to the headings in the original file.
> Useful for maintaining both a print version and a browsable version of
> a site.

I have used this Perl script in the past. It is brilliant, but *obviously* requires you to install [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), if it is not already installed. If you are running Windows, then you could use [ActiveState Perl](http://www.activestate.com/perl).

Answer (score 1):

I know you are asking about Noetpad++ which implies you are using Windows, but do you have access to a Linux machine? If so, use the [`split`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split) command; it’s quite easy to use.

The basic format of the command is this:

```sh
split [options] filename prefix
```

In your case, a 4,000 line file being split into 20 parts would mean 200 lines per file; `-l 200`. So the command would be this:

```sh
split -l 200 -da 2 4000_line.html 4000_line_split_ --additional-suffix=".html"
```

Or use this command to explicitly set the number of chunks that you want via `-n 1/20` like this:

```sh
split -n 1/20 -da 2 4000_line.html 4000_line_split_ --additional-suffix=".html"
```

That will cleanly create 20 files of 200 lines each named as follows:

```sh
4000_line_split_00.html
4000_line_split_01.html
4000_line_split_02.html
4000_line_split_03.html
etc…
```